# Config oauth2 for dingo/api Laravel 4.2 has an error Argument 1 passed to

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, dingo-api

I am BeanNguyen.

I am a beginer with Laravel framework. So i want to build a webservice RestAPI (laravel 4.2).
I use https://github.com/dingo/api and oauth2 lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel to protect my api. But when i complete all config files and i use Postman ( https://www.getpostman.com/ ) to send request.

I have a error :

```
*ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Argument 1 passed to Dingo\Api\Auth\LeagueOAuth2Provider::__construct() must be an instance of League\OAuth2\Server\ResourceServer, instance of LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Authorizer given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/webservice/app/config/packages/dingo/api/config.php on line 110 and defined*
```

So please help me to fix this problem :). This is my config files:

**app\routes.php**

```
Route::api('v1', function () {

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'protected', 'protected' => true, 'providers' => 'oauth'], function () {

        Route::post('user', function () {
            $user = API::user();

            return $user;
        });
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'unprotected', 'protected' => false], function () {

    });
});
```

**app\config\packages\dingo\api\config.php**

```
'auth' => [
        'basic' => function ($app) {
            return new Dingo\Api\Auth\BasicProvider($app['auth']);
        },

        'oauth' => function ($app) {
            $provider = new Dingo\Api\Auth\LeagueOAuth2Provider($app['oauth2-server.authorizer'], false);

            $provider->setUserCallback(function($id) {
                return User::find($id);
            });

            $provider->setClientCallback(function($id) {
                return Client::find($id);
            });

            return $provider;
        }
    ],
```

app\config\packages\lucadegasperi\oauth2-server-laravel\oauth2.php

```
'grant_types' => [

        'password' => [
            'class'            => 'League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant',
            'access_token_ttl' => 604800,

            // the code to run in order to verify the user's identity
            'callback'         => function($username, $password){
                $credentials = [
                    'email'    => $username,
                    'password' => $password,
                ];

                if (Auth::once($credentials)) {
                    return Auth::user()->id;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        ],
    ],
```

and this is my problem:

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Argument 1 passed to Dingo\Api\Auth\LeagueOAuth2Provider::__construct() must be an instance of League\OAuth2\Server\ResourceServer, instance of LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Authorizer given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/webservice/app/config/packages/dingo/api/config.php on line 110 and defined
```

Please help me :), thank you very much :)

Comment: Noone can help me :(((((((

Answer (score 0):

My config (app\config\packages\dingo\api\config.php) looks like this which is pretty different than yours. On Laravel 4.2.

```
'auth' => [
        'oauth' => function ($app) {
            $provider = new Dingo\Api\Auth\LeagueOAuth2Provider($app['oauth2-server.authorizer']->getChecker());

            $provider->setUserResolver(function ($id) {
                return User::find($id);
            });

            $provider->setClientResolver(function ($id) {
                return Client::find($id);
            });

            return $provider;
        }
    ]
```